# Using PhoneGap, Angular2 TS and Onsen UI 2

Tags: cordova, angular, onsen-ui

I'm struggling to get a project running using PhoneGap, Angular2 for TypeScript **and** Onsen UI 2. The idea is to build the app for the different platforms using PhoneGap/Cordova, writing the application logic with Angular2 and the layout with Onsen2. However, since Angular2 and Onsen UI 2 are still in beta I couldn't find some documentation/papers/tutorials/books to get things started. I got Angular2+Onsen2 running, well at least a little bit... And I got PhoneGap and Onsen running, but all three won't work together. Does anyone have any tips/tutorials how to melt all three (for themselves pretty awesome) frameworks? I feel like I'm just missing the trick how to get them work together

Comment: OnsenUI bindings for Angular2 are on the way, it should be ready before the final release. Have you seen this? https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/onsenui/onsenui.d.ts It's not fully updated (v1.3.0) but it should work pretty OK with Onsen 2 as well.

Comment: I don't understand how this would help me to get all three frameworks working together? How ever, do you have any information about _when_ Onsen2 will be released? I'd love to use the new version, how ever, I don't want to wait another 6 months ;-)

Comment: Those bindings should make possible to use OnsenUI and Angular2 together easily. It should be ready in few weeks (possibly more than 1 month).